# Tableau download/export images using Rest api python

Tags: python, tableau-api

Need to download image from the tableau server using python script. Tableau Rest API doesn't provide any option to do so.I like to know what is proper way of downloading high resolution/full size image from tableau server using python or any other server scripting language.

Comment: Is the image the resulting dashboard? If so, you can use Tabcmd to export an image of the dashboard/sheet. https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/tabcmd_cmd.htm#id7cb8d032-a4ff-43da-9990-15bdfe64bcd0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest approach is to issue an HTTP GET request from Python to your Tableau Server and append a format string to the URL such as ".png" or ".pdf".

There are size options you can experiment with as well -- press the Share button to see the syntax.

You can also pass filter settings in the URL as query parameters

Comment: Hi @Alex Blakemore can you help me to pass filter values in query string in the URL? I have one dropdown and need to create image based on its value.But didn't find option to pass the filter parameters 
Thanks in advacne

Comment: At the end of the URL, append an & and then key=value pairs separated by commas. Here is a link to the manual section with examples. http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/help.htm#embed_filter_add.htm%3FTocPath%3DUser%2520Guide%7CEmbed%2520Views%2520and%2520Dashboards%7CExamples%7C_____1

Comment: Hi @AlexBlakemore the link is not available anymore. Do you have any other resource where I can find an example?

Comment: https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/embed_list.html look at the URL parameter section

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need to pass filter settings, Query View Image functionality has been added to the Server API (versions 2.5 and later). [Request documentation here](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/v10.2/api/rest_api/en-us/help.htm#REST/rest_api_ref.htm#Query_View_Image).

If you do need to pass filter settings, a work-around was posted on [Tableau Community Forums](https://community.tableau.com/thread/247077).